# How to query GraphQL local state to retrieve all objects with a particular value for an @client variable from a nested structure

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

Given below is the query that fetches a list of products and stores it in the apollo-client local cache. It retrieves a list of `products` and the list of `images` for every product

```
const GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
  query Products($cursor: String, $query: String, $imageCount: Int = 100) {
    products(first: 9, after: $cursor, query: $query) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          id
          selected @client
          title
          description
          images(first: $imageCount) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                originalSrc
                selected @client
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I have a bunch of `products` with `selected: true` and each of this products will have one or more `images` with `selected: true`. My intention is to query the local GraphQL cache, and retrieve all products along with their images so that I can then filter them on the basis of the `selected` flag

This is what I have tried so far.

I wrote the query below

```
export const GET_SELECTED_PRODUCTS = gql`
  {
    selectedProducts @client
  }
`;
```

I wrote the definitions for the above query in the `resolvers` section while creating the ApolloClient as shown below

```
{
  Query: {
    selectedProducts(root, variables, { cache }) {
      let data = [];
      try {
       //Is this the right way to query the cache??
        const results = cache.readQuery({
          query: gql`
            query Products {
              products {
                id
                selected @client
                images(first: 100) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      id
                      originalSrc
                      selected @client
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `
        });

        //code to filter selected products

        data = results.data;
      } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
      }
      return data;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the above query in a component as shown

```
export default () => {
  const { data: productsData = {} } = useQuery(GET_SELECTED_PRODUCTS);
  const { selectedProducts = [] } = productsData;
  //Render selected products
}
```

There is some network delay for the cache to be filled up with product(by executing the `GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY`). So when the component first renders, `GET_SELECTED_PRODUCTS` throws an error(as expected) as products are not yet in the cache. Once the products are in the cache, some mutations(marking `selected` field as true) are done on the product object as the user clicks on products. I was under the impression that when this mutation happens, the useQuery hook with execute the `GET_SELECTED_PRODUCTS` query again to fetch the latest update. But this is not happening. How can I hook up the component to change and fetch the latest query results when something changes on the product object?